# Moodle flexible_table shows empty first row

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, moodle

After changing in **Moodle** the **html_table** into **flexible_table**, I get the first **row** as completely **empty** and because of that the **sorting** doesn't work.
I changes the tables, because the html_table doesn't have sorting capabilities. 
The code is:

```
ob_start();
            $table = new flexible_table('Cars');
            $table->define_baseurl(new moodle_url("/blocks/cars/view.php"));
                $table->define_columns(array(
                    'carname',
                    'carnumberplate',
                    'carhiredate',
                    'city', 
                    'actions',
                ));
            $table->define_headers(array(
                    get_string('carname', 'block_cars'),
                    get_string('carnumberplate', 'block_cars'),
                    get_string('carhiredate', 'block_cars'),
                    get_string('city', 'block_cars'),
                    get_string('actions')
                ));
            $table->sortable(true, 'cars');
            $table->collapsible(false);

            $table->set_attribute('cellspacing', '0');
            $table->set_attribute('id', 'view-block-cars');
            $table->set_attribute('class', 'generaltable');
            $table->setup();
            // Add one blank line
            $table->add_data(NULL);

            $strdateformat = get_string('strftimedate');
            $strtimeformat = get_string('strftimetime');
            foreach ($cars as $car) {
                    $datestart = userdate($car->starttime, $strdateformat);
                    $dateend = userdate($car->endtime, $strdateformat);
                    $timestart = userdate($car->starttime, $strtimeformat);
                    $timeend = userdate($car->endtime, $strtimeformat);

                    $date = $datestart;
                    if ($datestart != $dateend) {
                        $date .= ' - '.$dateend;
                    }
                    $time = $timestart.' - '.$timeend;

                    $actions = array(
                        html_writer::link($car->get_view_url(), get_string('view')),
                    );
                    $actions = implode(' | ', $actions);

                    $row = array(
                        format_string($car->carname),
                        format_string($car->platenumber),
                        $date,
                        format_string($car->city),
                        $actions,
                    );
                    $table->add_data($row);
            }
            $table->finish_html();
            $out .= ob_get_clean();

        return $out;
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, double check that you are getting the field `carname` from your `$DB->get_records()` (I'm assuming you are using this function or one similar).

**Second**, it helps to identify the issue doing a `print_object($car->carname);` within the foreach to check if this is printing the data correctly. Also a `print_object($cars);` before your foreach and check the results

**Third**, If the data is printing correctly I highly suggest to debug your file and see what errors, warnings or notices messages you may be getting. Add the following lines after the `require "../../config.php";`

```
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Hi Andrew, the problem was `$table->add_data(NULL);` I changed it to `$data = array();` and it works. How to make the table sortable? I added `if ($table->get_sql_sort()) {...` from user/index.ph but It still wont sort the columns.